# how to automatically remove relative class file once delete a java source file?

Tags: java, ant

when i delete a souce file *Test.java*, rebuild the source file use javac task, the class file *Test.class* wont be remove automatically.
is there any workaround?

Comment: Now that *would* be a handy `ant` task.

Answer (score 3):

You can define ant target called `clean` (say) that would remove all the compiled class files. And in your ant target `compile` (say) specify the target `clean` as dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Not immediately.  You usually deal with it by removing everything and recompiling.

Most IDE's do this transparently, however, so you don't have to handle this yourself.  Any particular reason you are not using an IDE?